# Correctly import CSV data, even when possibly malformed

Tags: c++, parsing, csv, excel

I've created a CSV parser that tries to build a string table out of a CSV file. The goal is to handle CSV files as well as Excel.

### Input CSV file:

> ```
> First field of first row,"This field is multiline
>
> but that's OK because it's enclosed in double qoutes, and this
> is an escaped "" double qoute" but this one "" is not
>    "This is second field of second row, but it is not multiline
> because it doesn't start 
> with an immediate double quote"
> ```

### What Excel shows:

[image]

### My code:

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// Returns a pointer to the start of the next field, or zero if this is the
// last field in the CSV p is the start position of the field sep is the
// separator used, i.e. comma or semicolon newline says whether the field ends
// with a newline or with a comma
const wchar_t* nextCsvField(const wchar_t *p, wchar_t sep, bool *newline, const wchar_t **escapedEnd)
{
    *escapedEnd = 0;
    *newline = false;

    // Parse quoted sequences
    if ('"' == p[0]) {
        p++;
        while (1) {
            // Find next double-quote
            p = wcschr(p, L'"');
            // Check for "", it is an escaped double-quote
            if (p[1] != '"') {
                *escapedEnd = p;
                break;
            }
            // If we don't find it or it's the last symbol
            // then this is the last field
            if (!p || !p[1])
                return 0;
            // Skip the escaped double-quote
            p += 2;
        }
    }

    // Find next newline or comma.
    wchar_t newline_or_sep[4] = L"\n\r ";
    newline_or_sep[2] = sep;
    p = wcspbrk(p, newline_or_sep);

    // If no newline or separator, this is the last field.
    if (!p)
        return 0;

    // Check if we had newline.
    *newline = (p[0] == '\r' || p[0] == '\n');

    // Handle "\r\n", otherwise just increment
    if (p[0] == '\r' && p[1] == '\n')
        p += 2;
    else
        p++;

    return p;
}

typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::wstring> > StringTable;

// Parses the CSV data and constructs a StringTable
// from the fields in it.
StringTable parseCsv(const wchar_t *csvData, wchar_t sep)
{
    StringTable v;

    // Return immediately if the CSV data is empty.
    if (!csvData || !csvData[0])
        return v;

    v.resize(1);

    // Here we CSV fields and fill the output StringTable.
    while (csvData) {
        // Call nextCsvField.
        bool newline;
        const wchar_t *escapedEnd;
        const wchar_t *next = nextCsvField(csvData, sep, &newline, &escapedEnd);

        // Add new field to the current row.
        v.back().resize(v.back().size() + 1);
        std::wstring &field = v.back().back();

        // If there is a part that is escaped with double-quotes, add it
        // (without the opening and closing double-quote, and also with any ""
        // escaped to ". After that csvData is set to the part immediately
        // after the closing double-quote, so anything after the closing
        // double-quote is added as well (but unescaped).
        if (escapedEnd) {
            for (const wchar_t *ii = csvData + 1; ii != escapedEnd; ii++) {
                field += *ii;
                if ('"' == ii[0] && '"' == ii[1])
                    ii++;
            }
            csvData = escapedEnd + 1;
        }

        // If there was no escaped part, or the CSV is malformed, add anything
        // else "as is" (i.e. unescaped). Keep in mind that next might be NULL.
        if (next)
            field.append(csvData, next-1);
        else
            field += csvData;

        // If the field ends with a newline, add next row to the StringTable.
        if (newline) {
            if (field.empty())
                v.back().pop_back();
            v.resize(v.size() + 1);
        }

        // Set csvData to point to the start of the next field for the next
        // cycle.
        csvData = next;
    }

    // If the CSV ends with a newline, then there is an empty row added
    // (actually it's a row with a single empty string). We trim that empty
    // row here.
    if (v.back().empty() || (v.back().size() == 1 && v.back().front().empty()))
        v.pop_back();
}
```

### What I'm interested in:

Whether my code handles all the corner cases, especially empty elements, lines, etc., and any mistakes I might have made.

Comment: Why did it add a `"` after *quote*?

Comment: It seems Excel treats the rest of the field (after the closing double-quote and before the next comma/newline) as an unescaped part of the same field. This is a malformed CSV anyway.

Comment: I may be a bit slow, but I'm not clear what you consider good data, what you consider malformed data that should be handled correctly and what you consider malformed data that can be handled incorrectly.  Perhaps give some C string examples of each.  Also, do you handle empty fields correctly?

Comment: My idea is to handle it exactly as Excel does (even when it's malformed). That's why the screenshot from Excel, it shows how it treats malformed data.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you testing against? Microsoft's understanding of CSV has changed a number of times through the years, even within the last decade.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Excel 2007 in my case.

Answer (score 3):

- I'm not sure it's best to return `0` from `nextCsvField()`.  Since the function is to return a pointer, consider returning `NULL` (or `nullptr` if you have C++11).  This function also shouldn't return a `const` pointer if the return value (a valid `wchar_t`) will be modified.
- You're using a "Yoda condition" here:

  > ```
  > if ('"' == p[0])
  > ```

  This isn't too common, and it may still be prone to error.  Either way, you should have your compiler warnings up high so that any accidental assignments in conditions will be reported.
- You should still use curly braces for single-line statements, as it could benefit maintenance.